# How can I connect multiple text field inputs along with their functions to one button in tkinter python?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, textfield

I have this issue where I need to display other function's values using the only button which is Calculate in this case. The first function is displayed but the other function not while using its text input field.

I've tried copying, using the same code expect changing the names.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

n_num = list(map(int, input('Enter mean numbers: ').split()))
n = len(n_num)

get_sum = sum(n_num)
mean = get_sum / n

print("Mean / Average is: " + str(mean))



def mean_result (label_mean_result,num):
    n_num = list(map(int,num.get()))
    n = len(n_num)

    get_sum = sum(n_num)
    mean = get_sum /n
    label_mean_result.config(text=f"Mean Result = {mean}")
    return


def median_result (label_median_result,num):
    n_num = list(map(int,num.get()))
    n = len(n_num)
    n_num.sort()

    if n % 2 == 0:
        median1 = n_num[n // 2]
        median2 = n_num[n // 2 - 1]
        median = (median1 + median2) / 2
    else:
        median = n_num[n // 2]
        label_median_result.config(text=f"Median Result = {median}")
    #print("Median is: " + str(median))
    return


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x200+100+200')

root.title('Final program')


## Mean input and output
meanInput = tk.StringVar()

labelMean = tk.Label(root, text="Mean input:").grid(row=1, column=0)

labelResult = tk.Label(root)

labelResult.grid(row=7, column=2)

entryNum1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=meanInput).grid(row=1, column=2)

mean_result = partial(mean_result, labelResult, meanInput)

buttonCal = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=mean_result).grid(row=3, column=0)

#####

medianInput = tk.StringVar()

labelMedian = tk.Label(root, text="Median input:").grid(row=2, column=0)

labelResult2 = tk.Label(root)

labelResult2.grid(row=7, column=2)

entryNum2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=medianInput).grid(row=2, column=2)

median_result= partial(median_result, labelResult2, medianInput)

root.mainloop()
```

I expect results when I input values from both functions using the only button in this case which is Calculate. As a result of that, I'd love to know how to connect multiple functions to one button and show their results. Like for example, the first function displays "mean function" result, however; the second function "median" is not connected and displayed while clicking at Calculate button.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a little confused as to what you want to do. Did you want to calculate the mean and median with values inputted into the entry widget? then display it on in a label?

Comment: No problems man!, yes! using one button which is in the case "calculate" calling both functions and display them together into labels. I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
from statistics import median, mode, stdev

class Calculator(tk.Frame):
    """Calculate mean median mode and standard deviation"""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        #setup tkinter frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        parent = parent

        self.makeWidgets()

    def makeWidgets(self):
        """make and pack various widgets"""
        self.meanLabel = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.medianLabel = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.modeLabel = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.sdLabel = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.calcuateButton = tk.Button(self, text="Calculate!", command = self.calculate)
        self.meanLabel.pack()
        self.medianLabel.pack()
        self.modeLabel.pack()
        self.sdLabel.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.calcuateButton.pack()

    def calculate(self):
        self.listOfNumbers = self.entry.get()
        #get what is inputed into the entry widget
        self.listOfNumbers = self.listOfNumbers.split(' ')
        #split the input string by spaces
        for ind, i in enumerate(self.listOfNumbers):
            #convert each item in the list of strings of numbers to ints
            self.listOfNumbers[ind] = int(i)
        #calculate!
        self.calcMean()
        self.calcMedian()
        self.calcMode()
        self.calcSd()

    def calcMean(self):
        """calculate the mean"""
        mean = sum(self.listOfNumbers)/len(self.listOfNumbers)
        self.meanLabel.config(text='mean = ' + str(mean))
        return mean

    def calcMedian(self):
        """calculate the median"""
        med = median(self.listOfNumbers)
        self.medianLabel.config(text='median = ' + str(med))
        return med

    def calcMode(self):
        """calculate the mode"""

        Mode = max(set(self.listOfNumbers), key=self.listOfNumbers.count)
        self.modeLabel.config(text='mode = ' + str(Mode))
        return Mode

    def calcSd(self):
        """calculate the standard deviation"""
        sd = stdev(self.listOfNumbers)
        self.sdLabel.config(text='Standard deviation = ' + str(sd))
        return sd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('calculate mean, median, mode and standard deviation')
    root.geometry('400x200')
    Calculator(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Now this may be quite a bit different to what you had, but this is expandable and you can abstract things to suit your interest. I just find it much more readable

You calculated the median in your example, just thought it would be cleaner to use the statistics module. Mean is already pretty clean

I hope this helps :)

Edit; To include mode and sd;

Comment: I see what you are doing here, but mean and mode functions don't work! did you intend to leave it like so I can modify it? thank you so much though: )

Comment: How do you mean? it should be showing the mean and median in a label.
 Did you want to call the functions outside of the gui?

Comment: It shows both mean and median but they are not calculated! for example, if I input 12345, the output would be 12345

Comment: it's because that is one number, put a space between each number
The median of ['12345'] is 12345, the median of ['1','2','3','4','5'] is 3 right?
Its how the program differentiates between different numbers.

Comment: Otherwise how will it know if i mean 12, or 1,2

Comment: enter in the entry widget '1 2 3 4 5' without quotations

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to calculate mode and Standard Deviation of the data as well?

Comment: Hope that will do the trick... Mode might need another look at, wasn't sure if i should return 1 or return multiple numbers that have equivalent counts?

I'll leave that to you :)